# Upper bound of something

Tags: calculus

I want to find an upper bound of 
$$\left | \frac{(x-x^2)}{2}\left [ \frac{1-\ln(x+N)(s+1)}{(x+N)^{s+2}} \right ] \right |$$
where $s>-1$, $0<x<1$ and $N\geq 1$. Can there be one of the form $A/N^{s+2}$, where $A$ is constant? Here is what I did.

$$|x-x^2|\leq 1/4$$
$$|1-\ln(x+N)(s+1)|\leq \ln(x+N)(s+1)+1< N(s+2)$$
$$\frac{1}{(x+N)^{s+2}}<\frac{1}{N^{s+2}}$$
so the upper bound can be

$$\frac{1}{8}\frac{s+2}{N^{s+1}}.$$

Comment: you will ask us to check all your formulas ?... and it is obvious that here you need the upper bound for deriving **something**

Comment: @user1952009 I thought if there is a better estimation where the denominator is $N^{s+2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For example, for $N$ large, $s=0$, and $x=\frac 12$ your expression becomes $\frac 18 \cdot \frac {\ln (\frac 12+N)}{(\frac 12+N)^2}$, which will exceed any $\frac A{N^2}$ when the log gets big enough.

Comment: OK. Does my estimation look fine?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me.